# confused how to use IDL to communicate with Ethovision

Tags: c++

Ethovision is an old computer vision software writen in c++ used mainly for tracking mice. It has the possibility to Real Time Export this data and i have been given the task to establish a program that use this data. i am quite confused on how as i am a beginer programmer and have only done web design so far.

I have been provided with some IDL files but i have no clue what im supposed to do with them and im just really confused in general. Does any one have any general idea on what i should do/read to extract this data.

Sorry if this sounds dumb, im new at this.

Comment: IDL defines interfaces. They're like a header file so to speak. You can't "use IDL". IDL can describe e.g. an IIOP or COM interface which you **can** use. What is it you're using? Is there a link to the API, SDK, vendor documentation?

Comment: i see. There isnt any link to an API, SDK, vendor documentation. I have been given some old power point that does speak about COM interface. I thought that the IDL was some kind of API definition for C++ functions that i had to use for the COM process. Am i missing soomething here?

Comment: Yes. In the context of COM the IDL can represent a typelib. You might even be able to #import that on MSVC. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/midl/importing-files-and-type-libraries

Comment: In this context it might be a lot simpler to tinker with this from another language before you decide how to harness it in C++ (if at all). COM is language agnostic. C#, VB.Net all have COM interop and allow you to add COM components as non-CLR references.

Comment: If its a typelib does it mean the functions are defined within that file? or are they somewhere else? If theyre defined in c++ how would i import them in another language?

Answer (score 1):

> **Q.** If its a typelib does it mean the functions are defined within that file? or are they somewhere else? If theyre defined in c++ how would i import them in another language?

No. The interface is only described in that file. But in the case of COM "type libraries", there will be GUID identifiers for

- the type library
- classes (co-classes)
- interfaces (IUnknown/IDispatch derived)
- search the registry (regedit.exe, regedt32.exe) for the typelibrary GUID to find what *registered COM component* implements it.

  > If it's a wellknown component, dropping the GUID in Google could reveal some useful documentation

You can import these in many languages that have COM interop, like VB6, C#, VB.Net, and yes even C++ provided that you either use MSVC's builtin extensions or external libraries to make it workable.

I'm going to give some pointers here assuming that you want the MSVC (Visual Studio's C++ compiler) route on windows:

- Use oleview.exe to view typelibraries. You can also view dlls that have their typelibraries *as embedded resources*. You can then save the TLB file separately, or view the IDL
- Use MIDL.EXE (The [MIDL Compiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/midl/using-the-midl-compiler-2)), specifically for COM https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/midl/midl-and-com
- I recommand [`#import` directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/hash-import-directive-cpp?view=vs-2019) which basically does the same as generating the header/implementation files and including them in one line

### TL;DR Summary

If you can, don't do this from C++. The reason is that COM interfaces speak "high level" types that just require tedious, error prone handling in C or C++ (using wrappers like [`CComBSTR` or `bstr_t`](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5234/Secure-BSTR-and-Other-Data-Wrappers)).

In a language like C# you get all the marshalling and threading (["apartments"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/processes--threads--and-apartments)) guarantees for free.